# Opening a static form/jFrame on clicking on button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two JFrames. The first one is defined as `public firstJframe` and the second one is defined as `public static final jFrame`. I want to open the second JFrame on clicking a button on the first JFrame. How can I do this?

`.setVisible` does not work for this. I really don't know how to proceed with this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: .setVisible() certainly will work. Show some code, as you question is too vague for us to help you.

Comment: are you sure that the second frame has been instantiated? check also the size of the second frame: should be no problem opening a frame from another

Answer (score 0):

Try calling revalidate() for the object you want to update(in your case the second frame).

Example:

```
  JButton myButton = new JButton("Open new window");
  JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("New Window");

   myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   newFrame.pack();
   newFrame.setVisible(true);
   newFrame.revalidate();
   }
   });
```

**Update**

If that does not work, try calling this:

```
newFrame.invalidate();
newFrame.validate();
```

Answer (score -1):

I propose: 
under the `button` `type`:

this.dispose

```
new public static final jFrame.setvisible(true);
```